# Connecting to virtual machine on host computer

Tags: virtualization, freebsd

I ultimately wish to run a FreeBSD virtual machine on my Vista computer to act as a server so I can test several projects. Im getting the FreeBSD vm set up with apache, php etc but how do I connnect to the vm from my computer? How do I configure/find the ip address I need to connect to?

Thanks.

Comment: I think we need to know what virtualization technology / server you are using...

Comment: You might better off asking this superuser/serverfault. Unless you want to access the computer programmitcally - in which case what technology do you want to connect via?

Comment: I do apologise for posting in the incorrect place. I am using VMware.

Comment: Already on serverfault - http://serverfault.com/questions/71708/connecting-to-virtual-machine-on-host-computer

Answer (score 1):

In the settings for your VM, you should set the NIC to bridged mode to expose it to your network, then assign it an IP like you would any other computer. If you give it a DNS entry you can connect by hostname, if not you can connect by IP.

Answer (score 0):

On the FreeBSD guest, open the terminal and type `ifconfig` to determine it's IP address. If Apache is configured correctly (make sure the www service is started) and your firewall settings aren't blocking it, you should be able to use this IP from Vista to access the site on FreeBSD.